# Unable to lunch json file on index.html

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
booksData = open(
r'C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\Desktop\pool1\books.json').read()
data = json.loads(booksData)
def index(request):
    context = {'books': data}
    return render(request, 'books\index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
{% for book in books %}

<p>{{book.title }} </p>
<img src="{{book.url}}" width="200px">

{% endfor %}
</body>

</html>
```

I am not able to lunch a JSON data on the index.html file and the image is not shown but its icon is seen
and Books text is display there is no any Book text

Comment: Can you give an example of the url you are trying to pass to the `img` tag and also I don't understand the part of "Books text is display there is no any Book text" maybe add a screenshot of what the page looks like

Comment: You're sure that the "url" field in your JSON actually contains legitimate URLs?

Answer (score -1):

move the open and load statement inside the view.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def index(request):
     booksData = open('C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\Desktop\pool1\books.json').read()
     data = json.loads(booksData)
     context = {'books': data}
     return render(request, 'books\index.html', context)
```

It is preferable that the file be under your project and you get it by settings variable.

Comment: "Hope it works" is not an answer, and it's clear that isn't going to change the result.